# How to Split Data in TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, unpivot

need some help figuring out how to split up some data

the Data Currently looks like this

```
╔═════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ Name Data1 Data2 Data3 Field1 field2 Field3 ║
╠═════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ a     1      2     3     x      y      z    ║
╚═════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

I need to split that data so that it looks like this

```
+-----------------+
| name data field |
+-----------------+
| a     1     x   |
| a     2     y   |
| a     3     z   |
+-----------------+
```

can anyone help me with this

Comment: @ethrbunny Asking that after two answers?

Answer (score 7):

Depending on your version of SQL Server. Starting in SQL Server 2008, you can *unpivot* the data using `CROSS APPLY`:

```
SELECT t.name,
  x.Data,
  x.Field
FROM YourTable t
CROSS APPLY 
(
    VALUES
        (t.Data1, t.Field1),
        (t.Data2, t.Field2),
        (t.Data3, t.Field3)
) x (Data, Field);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/52999a/2).

This can also be done using the `UNPIVOT` and the `PIVOT` function in SQL Server 2005+:

```
select name, data, field
from
(
  select name, left(col, len(col) -1) col, value,
    row_number() over(partition by left(col, len(col) -1) order by col) rn
  from
  (
    select name, 
      cast([Data1] as varchar(10)) Data1, 
      cast([Data2] as varchar(10)) Data2, 
      cast([Data3] as varchar(10)) Data3, 
      [Field1], [field2], [Field3]
    from yourtable
  ) src
  unpivot
  (
    value
    for col in ([Data1], [Data2], [Data3], 
                [Field1], [field2], [Field3])
  ) unpiv
) u
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for col in (data,field)
) piv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0e421/5)

Both give the result:

```
| NAME | DATA | FIELD |
-----------------------
|    a |    1 |     x |
|    a |    2 |     y |
|    a |    3 |     z |
```

Comment: And on 2005 the same can be achieved with `UNION ALL` [Amended Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/52999a/4)

Comment: how do i dump the results of the cross apply into a table?

Comment: @Greg you can use `SELECT INTO newtable` - see this demo -- http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/52999a/6

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to do this (just look at bluefeet's answer), but a simple way can be using `UNION ALL` :

```
SELECT [Name], Data1 AS Data, Field1 AS Field
FROM YourTable
UNION ALL
SELECT [Name], Data2 AS Data, Field2 AS Field
FROM YourTable
UNION ALL
SELECT [Name], Data3 AS Data, Field3 AS Field
FROM YourTable
```

And [here is a fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0e421/6) with a demo for this (courtesy of bluefeet).

Comment: This query also transforms your horizontal table into a vertical.  Make it a view if you want it to persist and query off it.